# parsing JSON data returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  {
   "EWsd5eHpriTDfhNTJux8IByrkUD2":{
      "appointmentDetail":"",
      "appointmentPrescription":"",
      "email":"ronaldoraj57@gmail.com",
      "firstName":"Raja",
      "gender":"Male",
      "hospitalInformation":"",
      "icNumDOB":990708,
      "icNumID":4222,
      "icNumState":7,
      "lastName":"Shilan",
      "phoneNumber":"+60123456789",
      "username":"rajashilan"
   }
}
```

I'm retrieving this JSON data from a firebase database. [link to the firebase database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wplju.png).

I'm trying to access the data in the JSON one by one, for example: 
email: ronaldoraj57@gmail.com.

```html
databaseRef.orderByChild("icNumID")
.equalTo(parseInt(search1))
.on("value",function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());

    var dataJSON=JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
    var json=JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML=json.email;

    if(snapshot.val()==null){
        window.alert("IC Number not registered in  database.");
    }

    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
         console.log(data.key);
    });
});
```

Comment: From you json it looks like you would need `data['EWsd5eHpriTDfhNTJux8IByrkUD2'].email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataSnapshot.forEach()` to loop over the nodes matching your query, and use `DataSnapshot.exists()` to see if there are any results:

```
databaseRef
  .orderByChild("icNumID")
  .equalTo(parseInt(search1))
  .on("value", function(results){
    if(!results.exists()){
      window.alert("IC Number not registered in  database.");
    }
    else {
      results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        var json = snapshot.val();
        console.log(json);
        document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML=json.email;
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: worked like a charm and is exactly what i wanted :) thank you so much kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use JSON methods at all. Try:

```
ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.child("email").val()
})
```

Comment: See Firebase reference pages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: thank you! unfortunately it didn't work for me, but yeah thanks for your time!